# C# Optimize creation of new object (Too much, ugly code)

Tags: c#, constructor, getter-setter

I'm afraid this question might be stupid / I'm not entirely how to ask this but here we go:

I'm currently working on a project where I need to create a lot of new objects.
The properties are set by multiple ifs, and the code looks very messy to me.

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new <see cref="StockItem"/> based on the <see cref="Article"/> of the given <param name="input"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input"></param>
public static StockItem CreateStockItem(InputParameterCreateStockItem input)
{
    var returnStockItem = new StockItem();

    //If there is an imob item, start from there and update everything
    if (input.StockItem != null)
    {
        returnStockItem = input.StockItem;
    }
    else
    {
        //When creating a stock item, the status is ALWAYS 1
        returnStockItem.Status = 1;
    }

    #region Properties
    returnStockItem.PartTypeNo = (Int32)input.Article.ArticleNumberPrefix + "-" + input.Article.ArticleNumber.Value.ToString("D8");
    returnStockItem.Kardex = ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.KardexT) ?? String.Empty;
    returnStockItem.WeldNumber = input.WeldNumber;
    returnStockItem.ObjectNo = ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.ObjectNoT) ?? ConvertHelper.GetObjectNo(input.Article);
    returnStockItem.Synonymous = ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.SynonymousT) ?? String.Empty;
    returnStockItem.ExtSerialNo = ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.ExtSerialNoT) ?? String.Empty;
    returnStockItem.ArticleReference = (ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.ArticleReferenceT)) ??
                                   ConvertHelper.RemoveColorCodeFromReference(input.Article.Reference, input.ColorList);
    returnStockItem.ArticleName = ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.ArticleNameT) ??
                              ConvertHelper.GetCorrectTranslation(input.Article.Names, "ENG");
    returnStockItem.Length = ConvertHelper.GetMeasurementInMeters(input.Article, ConvertHelper.ImobLengthT, ConvertHelper.ClsLengthT);
    returnStockItem.Width = ConvertHelper.GetMeasurementInMeters(input.Article, ConvertHelper.ImobWidthT, ConvertHelper.ClsWidthT);
    returnStockItem.Height = ConvertHelper.GetMeasurementInMeters(input.Article, ConvertHelper.ImobHeightT, ConvertHelper.ClsHeightT);
    returnStockItem.Weight =
        Decimal.Parse(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.ImobWeightT))
            ? ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.ImobWeightT)
            : ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.ClsWeightT) ?? "0");
    returnStockItem.DepreciationCode = ConvertHelper.GetTechSpecValue(input.Article.TechnicalSpecifications, ConvertHelper.DepreciationCodeT) ??
                                   (input.Article.DepreciationCode != null ? input.Article.DepreciationCode.InsuranceValueCode.ToString() +
                                    input.Article.DepreciationCode.ActualValueCode.ToString() +
                                    input.Article.DepreciationCode.RevaluationCode.ToString() : String.Empty);
    returnStockItem.Value = ConvertHelper.GetValue(input.Article);
    returnStockItem.ValueDate = ConvertHelper.GetValueDate(input.Article);
    returnStockItem.Brand = ConvertHelper.GetBrand(input.Article);
    returnStockItem.Remarks = ConvertHelper.GetRemarks(input.Article);
    returnStockItem.InsuranceValue = ConvertHelper.GetInsuranceValue(input.Article);
    returnStockItem.StockItemGroupID = ConvertHelper.GetStockItemGroupId(input.Article, input.ClsImobArticleGroups, input.StockItemGroups);
    returnStockItem.StockAllocations = StockAllocationDAO.GetStockAllocationsForArticleGroupIDs(input.Article, input.ClsAssignedArticleGroups, input.ClsUnAssignedArticleGroups, input.ClsImobArticleGroups, input.StockAllocationsDictionaryByCode, input.StockAllocationsDictionaryByName);
    #endregion

    //AddMotherStockItemColorCode(input.Article, stockItem);

    return returnStockItem;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better (more readable) way to do this.

Things I have already done:

- Moved more complicated code to Helper Class (`ConvertHelper`)
- Created an Input Parameter Object (I needed a lot of lists to check certain things)
- Moved the whole method to a Factory (feels unnecessary?)

But the whole thing just feels messy to me.

Thank you,
Thomas

Comment: maybe this is better for CodeReview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? You should also clarify what you mean with "better"? readbility / performance etc.

Comment: You should be able to remove the ConvertHelper from ConvertHelper.GetMeasurementInMeters if your 'using' is correct

Comment: Remove all that `ConvertHelper` stuff and create Extension Methods. C# is not java.

Comment: @derape Thanks, that might be a better place to to post this.

Comment: @Rawling What do you mean by that? I'm just looking for help so there's no need to get mean.

Comment: The biggest issue is that `StockItem` violates SRP. It contains both information about the article itself and information about its stock status.

Comment: @Rawling I should rename my return value, I updated the code. Thanks! :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos I can't really do much about that, this is based on a database that is nearly 2 decades old.

Comment: Then at least you should split this method into two parts. One takes an article as input and copies/computes all article related properties.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried AutoMapper?
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper
Take some time looking through the documentation you'll see you'll get that time back really quick.